# How do I determine which active contributors have a deep understanding of traditional Jewish beliefs?

Tags: discussion, support

I am a Christian believer, by the standard that I ascribe to both the Nicene Creed and the Apostles’ Creed.

However, there are some areas in which my beliefs differ from those of every independent church and organized denomination I’ve ever been a part of.

I’m hoping to ask someone who knows the Jewish foundation that preceded Christianity, as well as the foundations of Jewish traditions and beliefs developed since Biblical times.

I’ve tried reading through the answers to what I think are relevant questions, but I’m afraid that I just don’t have the theological background of Judaism to analyze whether a particular statement is considered to be authoritative, or a load of dingo’s kidneys.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

While you're welcome to ask questions of specific people in chat, on the main site it's really not appropriate to either limit questions to specific individuals or even to people of a specific faith. This site is run so that answers are meant to be supported by external literature. Neither your nor my personal convictions matter as long as we can provide good answers that accurately represent the study of the Bible out there in the world. This matches how Bible colleges are run, where students will be expected to accurately explain not just how their own faith or denomination interprets the Bible, but also how other denominations and even other religions interpret the Bible. Catholics will sometimes give answers referencing Protestant commentaries, Protestants will give answers referencing Jewish commentaries, and Jews will give answers referencing atheist commentaries, and so forth.

If you really are after answers from Judaism, consider asking at the [Judaism site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) instead. There are many more Jewish users there than here. But I'd caution you not to necessarily expect great insights into pre-Christian Jewish religion from Jewish scholars after that. It is not controversial to say that the Judaism we know today is founded not just on the Hebrew Bible but also the Midrash and Talmud. Judaism has adapted in several ways from the theocratic temple-centred religion you see in the Pentateuch.

If you do want to know about that period, the term you'll want to use in your searches is "Second Temple Judaism". That will help you find relevant information in both Jewish, Christian, and secular scholarship.

Finally, if your differences from most Christians are really more of a doctrinal than exegetical nature, then you should consider asking at the [Christianity site](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: IS it okay, as a non-Jew, to ask questions about Judaism on the Judaism site (which I didn't even know existed, by the way; I'm REALLY pretty new at using the entire Stack functions).

Comment: Of course, though they have their own rules. They don't allow comparative religion questions for example.

Comment: I'm about to post a question regarding the origin of "logos" in John 1 to be 2nd Temple "memra" instead of Stoic "logos".  See [this article](https://vridar.org/2014/07/03/the-pre-christian-jewish-logos/).  Should I post it in BH.SE or C.SE ?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Probably here?